# Potential difference between A.C. circuit

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

I the following A.C circuit . I could not understand why the V$_{AB}$ does not depend on non zero value of R$_0$.

[image]

According to me it should depend on it . As it will decide the amount of current in that part of wire which will decide the potential at B.

Comment: Who says it doesn't?

Comment: @ThePhoton in my book it is written

Comment: Can you share the exact quote and the context?

Comment: @ThePhoton http://dc.allenbpms.in/testpaper/solution/d8541-4-636197522366039953-004s.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the original question you added in comments:
[image]

$$V_{AB} = v_0\left(\frac{R_0}{j\omega{}L+R_0}-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

$$\frac{V_{AB}}{v_0} = \frac{2R_0 - j\omega{}L-R_0}{2(j\omega{}L+R_0)}$$

$$\frac{V_{AB}}{v_0} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{R_0-j\omega{}L}{R_0+j\omega{}L}$$

Now consider the term $\frac{R_0-j\omega{}L}{R_0+j\omega{}L}$. Since the numerator and the denominator have equal magnitude, the magnitude of the quotient is always 1, so the magnitude of $V_{AB}$ is always $\frac{v_0}{2}$.

The phase of the quotient is 
$$2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{R_0}{\omega{}L}\right)$$
but the original question only asks about the r.m.s. value (which you didn't correctly relate in your post), so this variation doesn't matter.

Comment: Here What is $j$

Comment: Sorry, that's Electrical Engineering speak for $i$.

Comment: Can you expalin it in simple words for a high school student

Comment: If you haven't learned enough math to follow what I wrote, then you aren't ready to answer this question yet.

Comment: @Koolman It is a mathematical trick: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/impcom.html